# Title Text formatting issue in Wordpress/Beaver Builder

Tags: wordpress, formatting

```
[K1][1]
[K2][2]
[K3][3]
```

I do SEO optimization for clients and I have one for whom I changed her home page title. (changed the wording and H1 tag. the title was originally split into two separate h1 tags. I made it one and changed the wording)

However after changing it the formatting is not cooperating. It looks fine when saved and published in the editor (2 lines stacked and left justified). But in a separate browser it looks different (centered and not stacked) and from her end it looks even another way. (stacked completely differently (3 lines) than how it appears in the editor) Mobile view is another view altogether. I am not a webdesigner. I have no idea what i did wrong

I moved the spacing block inserted to the right of the text to no avail. Resizing it and moving it on top of and on the bottom of the text. I am so confused because its right in the editor.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2rFI.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMf0m.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XqyU.jpg
```

Comment: it is best if you can show here screenshot and link

Comment: K1: is my view after publishing in the editor. K2 is her view. K3 is my view in a sep browser. I am trying to get it to publish as K1

Comment: I'm not sure I did that right but I tried to add pictures.

Comment: here is the website https://comerfordnutrition.com/